# Is it possible to increase cash reward doing Roman's job?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

When I'm doing a job for Roman, is there a way to increase the amount of cash earned?

Will customer give me more cash :

- If I arrive quickly to him ?
- If I bring him to his destination quickly ?
- If I bring him to his destination without any accident ?
- If I follow the traffic and drive respectfully (stop at red light...) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Arriving quickly to the fare has no bearing on your earnings
- Bringing the person to their destination faster may get you more money ([source](http://guides.gamepressure.com/grandtheftautoiv/guide.asp?ID=4704))
- Damaging the car too much will cause the person to flee ([source](http://gta.wikia.com/Taxi_Driver))
- Driving by the rules of the road (like stop lights) has no effect

Comment: It should also be noted that driving ridiculously fast may cause your passenger to flee (from personal experience).